# Linux Mint 19.2 DNS not resolving after moving home on its own partition

Tags: dns, linux-mint

A bit of history to explain my issue:
I freshly installed Linux Mint 19.2 MATE 64bits on a new laptop.

After the installation I wanted to move the home directory on its own partition. I followed these [instructions](https://www.maketecheasier.com/move-home-folder-ubuntu/)

I messed up a step in the middle as I ended up stuck on a login loop (back to the login screen after typing credentials). 
I managed to fix it:

- /etc/psswd was pointing at the wrong path for my profile
- home directory was own by root, changing it to my username helped

Problem is that I no longer have access to internet (Wifi). I'm suspecting some permissions problems somewhere but don't know where to start my searches. ls -l / shows all folders with root as owner except my home folder that I manually changed.

Now for the problem itself:

I can ping IP addresses in the terminal but pinging a domain name returns

```
ping: google.com: Name or service not known
```

Here are a few command results I used to narrow the problem down:

```
~$ ll /etc/resolv.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 Nov 17 13:15 /etc/resolv.conf -> /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

```
~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#    DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.
```

```
~$ systemd-resolve --status
Failed to get global data: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.resolve1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
```

```
~$ systemctl status systemd-resolved.service
● systemd-resolved.service - Network Name Resolution
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: **failed** (Result: resources) since Sun 2019-11-17 13:13:14 GMT; 5min ago
   Docs: man:systemd-resolved.service(8)
       https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/resolved
       https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-network-configuration-managers
       https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-resolver-clients
       Nov 17 13:13:14 y systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: Service has no hold-off time, scheduling restart.
       Nov 17 13:13:14 y systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
       Nov 17 13:13:14 y systemd[1]: Stopped Network Name Resolution.
       Nov 17 13:13:14 y systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
       Nov 17 13:13:14 y systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: **Failed** with result 'resources'.
       Nov 17 13:13:14 y systemd[1]: **Failed to start Network Name Resolution.**
```

I've been googling for the past 4h but cannot find what is causing the problem.

Thanks for any information.

#### UPDATE:

- I tried booting with an older kernel with no success
- I tried booting from a live USB, everything works as expected
- I noticed that if I restart too early after booting, I have a message saying mate-settings-daemon is not responding. Google hasn't helped so far to identify why but it is a recurring problem many people encountered over the years.
- the time to boot increased quite a lot. systemd-analyze blame reveals that NetworkManager.service and NetworkManager-wait-online.service are using 31s out of the 32s needed to boot. I'm assuming this is because of a timeout while trying to reach a specific domain.

#### temporary workaround

breaking the symbolic link of resolv.conf and use a simple file with a nameserver does the job but I'm not sure what it implies down the chain to bypass resolvconf

```
rm -rf /etc/resolv.conf
echo "namesever 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf
chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Several OS directories are owned by *non*-root accounts, as they're used to store data by unprivileged daemons that themselves are using a dedicated service account and not the root account.

Try fully removing the `/var/lib/private/systemd/` directory. Its subdirectories belong to services which have DynamicUser=yes in their .service file, and the directory's ownership is actually used as the basis for the service account's UID.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. I've tried removing that directory but it did not help, even after rebooting.